# Protractor: Verify results are sorted

Tags: sorting, protractor, verify

Using Protractor I'm trying to verify if the sort works after I click on the sort by button. I've seen similar solutions here, but none of them works for my case.

On the page I have different values listed (15, 13, 67, ...) and for this I have home.myValues (using element.all). The flow would be:

1. store all numbers in an array and sort them with .slice().sort()
2. click on Sort by values button
3. store sorted numbers in an array
4. verify if sorted values match

Currently I have written the following, which doesn't work:

```
home.myValues.map(function(eachName) {
      return eachName.getText().then(function(unSortedValues) {
        initialSortedValues = unSortedValues.slice().sort();
        return initialSortedValues;
      });
    });

    // click on sort by values
    home.sortByValues.click();

    home.myValues.map(function(eachName) {
      return eachName.getText().then(function(checkSortedValues) {
        return checkSortedValues;
      });
      expect(initialSortedValues).toEqual(checkSortedValues);
    });
```

Any suggestion is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

After some additional research I found this to work:

```
// verify my values are sorted
        home.myValues.map(function(eachName) {
      return eachName.getText().then(function(unSortedValues) {
        return unSortedValues;
      });
    }).then(function(unSortedValues) {
      // click on sort by value
      home.sortByValue.click();

      sortedValues = unSortedValues.slice();
      sortedValues = sortedValues.sort(function(a, b){return a-b});

      home.myValues.map(function(eachName) {
        return eachName.getText().then(function(sortedValuesCheck) {
          return sortedValuesCheck;
        });
      }).then(function(sortedValuesCheck) {
        // verify sorted values equal expected
        expect(sortedValues).toEqual(sortedValuesCheck);
      });
    });
```